# ASP.NET in Chrome getting a strange focus_change nikkomsgchannel error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

Very recently I started to get some strange focus_change errors show up in the console window in Chrome when navigating through my ASP.NET web application (details below). I can't find anything on the internet that references a "nikkomsgchannel" and have no idea why my application is making a request to this external resource (it never used to!?). Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Request URL:

```
http://nikkomsgchannel/focus_change?focused=true&name=nikkonill&type=nikkonill&form=nikkonill
```

Request Headers:

```
Origin: http://localhost:50349
Referer: http://localhost:50349/ResearchEnquiry.aspx?EnquiryId=63
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.55 Safari/534.3
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you have Rapport software, try removing that.

I have just removed it and finally after weeks of those annoying messages when developing, they have disappeared.

Comment: This is the answer right here. Rapport is recommended by some banks as security software - it's meant to warn you if you use the same password on multiple sites, and other stuff.

http://www.trusteer.com/product/trusteer-rapport

Comment: You won't find Rapport in your list of programs to remove on Windows. Look for Trusteer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to entirely remove the Rapport software.

You can restart your computer in safe mode (F8 when it restarts), and change the type of the files containing "RapportNikko" from dll to something else, say old.