# (CSP) connect-src https://nikkomsgchannel

Tags: content-security-policy

Hope someone can shed some light on this because I have searched for months for an answer but to no avail.

I use a Content Security Policy on all my sites and record policy violations but constantly see attempts using **connect-src** for **https://nikkomsgchannel**

The entries look like this:

```
https://nikkomsgchannel/e?001600500058005b00330035006f0050002d0059005c005f005c00090051004
```

Does anyone else see this in their CSP violations?
What is nikkomsgchannel?
Should it be allowed connect-src access?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Requests to `nikkomsgchannel` appear to be due to a browser extension related to Trusteer Rapport [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707893/asp-net-in-chrome-getting-a-strange-focus-change-nikkomsgchannel-error)[[2]](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/s-bp7547AF8). Do not add it to `connect-src` as you have no control over what content gets injected. Just ignore it in your CSP reports.

Comment: Thanks so much Anand, first proper answer I have found to the elusive nikkomsgchannel. Much obliged.